# Elif statements not printing

Tags: python

I'm doing a basic rock paper scissors code for school, but my elif statements aren't running.

```
def player1(x):
    while x != 'rock' and x != 'paper' and x != 'scissors':
        print("This is not a valid object selection")
        x = input("Player 1? ")

def player2(x):
    while x != 'rock' and x != 'paper' and x != 'scissors':
        print("This is not a valid object selection")
        x = input("Player 2? ")

def winner():
    player1(input("Player 1? "))
    player2(input("Player 2? "))
    if player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock':
        print('Tie')
    elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper':
        print('Tie')
    elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper':
        print('Player 2 wins')
    elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock':
        print('Player 1 wins')
    elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors':
        print('Player 1 wins')
    elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock':
        print('Player 2 wins')
    elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors':
        print('Player 2 wins')
    elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper':
        print('Player 1 wins')
    elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors':
        print('Tie')

winner()
```

When I run this code, it asks for 'Player 1?' and won't accept anything other than rock, paper, or scissors. It then proceeds to do the same for player2. However, this is where the code ends, and it will not run my elif statements and print which player wins.

Edit: Solved. Thanks for helping a beginner. I was completely forgetting to return the strings and assign them to variables.

Comment: Wait, `player1` or `player2` aren't variables, they're function references... and you're comparing them to strings? I'd also think to return the `x` back to the callee if you want to use it in `winner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparisons:

```
elif player1 == "rock" and player2 == "rock":
# etc
```

will always fail, since both player1 and player2 are functions.

Instead, you need to return from your functions and assign those to variables. Let's cut out the validation for a minute and reduce this a little.

```
def choose(prompt):
    return input(prompt)

def winner(a, b):
    if a == 'rock':
        if b == 'rock': return None
        elif b == 'paper': return 2
        elif b == 'scissors': return 1
    elif a == 'paper':
        # etc

def play_game():
    p1_choice = choose("Player 1: ")
    p2_choice = choose("Player 2: ")
    return winner(p1_choice, p2_choice)
```

Note that a nicer-looking trick for these chains of elifs is to put them in a dictionary and index the dictionary instead.

```
RESULT_DICT = {"rock": {"rock": None,
                        "paper": 2,
                        "scissors": 1},
               "paper": {"rock": 1,
                         "paper": None,
                         "scissors": 2},
               "scissors": {"rock": 2,
                            "paper": 1,
                            "scissors": None}}

def winner(a, b):
    return RESULT_DICT[a][b]
```

Comment: I'd probably `return None if a == b else RESULT_DICT[a][b]`... then you can remove 33% of that dict.

Comment: @TemporalWolf yep, me too, then roll all the choices and all the results into class member Enums and do input validation that way. But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: `return None if a == b else ((2 if b == "Paper" else 1) if a == "Rock" else ((2 if b == "Scissors" else 1) if a == "Paper" else (2 if b == "Rock" else 1)))` No dict necessary. I'll see myself out.

Comment: I feel like we're working in opposite directions:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47f9d388e53de3124e5c5f2d5a9cc1ab

Comment: @TemporalWolf ick, that 200 character line physical hurt me. lol

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to x inside `player1` isn't doing anything. As soon as the function returns, the value assigned to x is dropped. That means you are discarding your input! Then you are comparing the *function* `player1` to a *string* that might or might not match your input.

Suggestion for debugging: Whenever you have a flow-of-control problem, print out the control variable. Here, if you print player1, you will see something surprising.